# How to automatically run my java function periodically when the Apache tomcat server is started?

Tags: java, function, jsp, tomcat, setinterval

I have a java function which checks and modify values in my SQL database to avoid errors, i need it to be executed automatically on server startup as well as on restart. i created a jsp page to call this function as jsp support "setInterval" in which i can run it automatically after every 3 minutes to remove errors from my database now i need it to be executed automatically on server startup. can anyone guide me on this?

the following is my jsp code:

```
setInterval(function(){Autolf();},60000);

function Autolf()
{

$.post('autolgfn.jsp',
        {
    abc:1
        },
        function(response,status,xhr)
        {
            alert(response.trim());

        });

}
```

the above code calls function from a java page which is connected to database.
please help me to run it automatically on server startup and keep running after every 3 minutes. thanks in advance

Comment: One solution: Check on jsf managed beans @PostConstruct semantics

Comment: Maybe you could have a look to [quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` (or `Timer`) to start your process in the `contextInitialized` method and stops it in the `contextDestroyed` method.

It could look something like this:

```
private volatile ScheduledExecutorService executor;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
    executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = this.executor;

    if (executor != null)
    {
        executor.shutdown();
        this.executor = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what i have to write under context destroyer?

Comment: ok, but where do i have to put my java code?

Comment: in your war - either directly or in a jar in the war

Comment: how the above scheduled executor service identify my specific java function defined else where? sorry, am a beginner to programming.

Comment: The `myRunnable` would need to be a runnable you defined to call your function.

Comment: How can i define a runnable?

Comment: You write a class implementing runnable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: i had created a new class "myRunnable.java" implemented runnable and under public void run(), i had written my codes. Now how to connect myRunnable class with class which we implemented ServletContextListener? myRunnable is still underlined with red color in it, please help me to finish this

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Brett's answer:

Configure your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    ......
    <!-- force initialization as soon as Tomcat starts -->
    <load-at-startup>1</load-at-startup> 
</servlet>

<!-- configure the context listener -->
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.acme.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

MyContextListener looks something like:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    // where the work happens
    final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { System.out.println("hello world"); }
    };

    // Brett's code here
    //....

}
```